# How can I mark a C++ class method as deprecated?

Tags: c++, deprecated, portability

I have a method in a C++ interface that I want to deprecate, with portable code.

When I Googled for this all I got was a Microsoft specific solution; [`#pragma deprecated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/deprecated-c-cpp?view=vs-2017) and [`__declspec(deprecated)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/deprecated-cpp?view=vs-2017).

If a general or fully-portable deprecation solution is not available, I will accept as a "second prize solution" one that can be used multiple  specific compilers, like MSVC and a GCC.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

In C++14, you can mark a function as deprecated using the `[[deprecated]]` attribute (see section 7.6.5 [dcl.attr.deprecated]).

> The *attribute-token* `deprecated` can be used to mark names and entities whose use is still allowed, but is discouraged for some reason.

For example, the following function `foo` is deprecated:

```
[[deprecated]]
void foo(int);
```

It is possible to provide a message that describes why the name or entity was deprecated:

```
[[deprecated("Replaced by bar, which has an improved interface")]]
void foo(int);
```

The message must be a string literal.

For further details, see [“Marking as deprecated in C++14”](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/marking-deprecated-c++14.html).

Comment: Can you use [[deprecated]] in a macro?

Comment: @Zammbi You should be able to, as macro is handled by the preprocessor before compilation. [[deprecated]] should appear (and let the compiler output related warnings) where the macro is evaluated.

Comment: And how about C++11?

Comment: `#define GRIKIFY(x) if (x) Grike(x)` how can I mark this `GRIKIFY` macro as deprecated?

Answer (score 131):

This should do the trick:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define DEPRECATED(func) func __attribute__ ((deprecated))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define DEPRECATED(func) __declspec(deprecated) func
#else
#pragma message("WARNING: You need to implement DEPRECATED for this compiler")
#define DEPRECATED(func) func
#endif

...

//don't use me any more
DEPRECATED(void OldFunc(int a, float b));

//use me instead
void NewFunc(int a, double b);
```

However, you will encounter problems if a function return type has a commas in its name e.g. `std::pair<int, int>` as this will be interpreted by the preprocesor as passing 2 arguments to the DEPRECATED macro. In that case you would have to typedef the return type.

Edit: simpler (but possibly less widely compatible) version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21265197/2651243).

Comment: Instead of #error, it would be better to #define DEPRECATED(func) func

Comment: @CesarB: I disagree; if there were no error, there would be no way to notice that something unexpected happened.

Comment: mxp: The deprecation is only a warning, and hence I'd say that a warning that it isn't supported is all you need.

Comment: Yep, I'd go for "#warning You need to implement DEPRECATED for this compiler", or some such. If that's impossible, then the porter can #define DEPRECATED(FUNC) FUNC, and live without it.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no standard way to output a compile warning in C++ :P
#pragma message will have to do.

Comment: Is it possible to mark a class Deprecated using this macro ?  with something like DEPRECATED(Class()); ?

Comment: gcc's attribute syntax allows for the attribute to be in the same places as `__declspec(deprecated)` now, so the macro can be simplified.

Comment: No need to pass argument to macros, just declare it as `#define DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)` and use as `DEPRECATED void MyApi()`

Comment: @bames53 & DarkWanderer I've added a new answer accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21265197/2651243. I thought it best not to change such a venerable answer just in case the new one breaks for older compilers.

Comment: Can I and other people use your DEPRECATED macro in a commercial closed source application?

Comment: @Vertexwahn Sure!

Comment: Note that this even works if you want to mark a 3rd party function deprecated, putting this statement after the include of a third party file makes it possible to mark some function deprectaed even outside of their header file.

Comment: So, shouldn't you delete this answer in favor of the simpler one?

Answer (score 68):

Here's a simplified version of my [2008 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295229/2651243):

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
#define DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)
#else
#pragma message("WARNING: You need to implement DEPRECATED for this compiler")
#define DEPRECATED
#endif

//...

//don't use me any more
DEPRECATED void OldFunc(int a, float b);

//use me instead
void NewFunc(int a, double b);
```

See also:

- [MSVC documentation for `__declspec(deprecated)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx)
- [GCC documentation for `__attribute__((deprecated))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes)
- [Clang documentation for `__attribute__((deprecated))`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#deprecated)

Comment: How do you `[[deprecate]]` your deprecated macros? :-)

Comment: I can't see any significant difference between those two answers. Why did you post it a second time?

Comment: You don't have to wrap it around the function so it's `DEPRECATED void foo(...);` instead of `DEPRECATED(void foo(...));`

Comment: You should have edited your 2008 answer rather than posting a new one.

Comment: This may not be as widely compatible as my other answer, hence I added this separately.

Comment: If you want to be a bit more complete, you can also add the message, e.g. `DEPRECATED("Use bar instead") void foo(...);`

Comment: @graham.reeds `#pragma deprecated("DEPRECATED")` :)

Comment: @graham.reeds, there isn't a way to use a C++ attribute *on* a macro, but if you just want to warn whenever the macro is invoked then in GCC 4.8+ as well as a few other compilers you can do `#define DEPRECATED _Pragma("GCC warning \"DEPRECATED is deprecated\"")`.  MSVC also has a pragma: `#define DEPRECATED __pragma(message("DEPRECATED is deprecated"))`.  If you're okay with informational messages instead of warnings you can get support from a few other compilers… take a look at [`HEDLEY_WARNING`](https://github.com/nemequ/hedley/blob/936b674230258626cac025b37d7af8eefc66b8df/hedley.h#L1776)

Comment: @nemequ ["THAT'S HEDY!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtf7SgIBwG0)

Comment: @FeRD: [It's not "Hedy", it's "Hedley".](https://youtu.be/g2Bp8SqYrnE?t=92) ☺

Answer (score 23):

In GCC you can declare your function with the attribute deprecated like this:

```
void myfunc() __attribute__ ((deprecated));
```

This will trigger a compile-time warning when that function is used in a .c file.

You can find more info under "Diagnostic pragmas" at 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html

Answer (score 14):

Here is a more complete answer for 2018.

These days, a lot of tools allow you to not just mark something as deprecated, but also provide a message. This allows you to tell people when something was deprecated, and maybe point them toward a replacement.

There is still a lot of variety in compiler support:

- C++14 supports `[[deprecated]]`/`[[deprecated(message)]]`.
- `__attribute__((deprecated))` is supported by GCC 4.0+ and ARM 4.1+
- `__attribute__((deprecated))` and `__attribute__((deprecated(message)))` is supported for:

  - GCC 4.5+
  - Several compilers which masquerade as GCC 4.5+ (by setting `__GNUC__`/`__GNUC_MINOR__`/`__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__`)
  - Intel C/C++ Compiler going back to at least 16 (you can't trust `__GNUC__`/`__GNUC_MINOR__`, they just set it to whatever version of GCC is installed)
  - ARM 5.6+
- MSVC supports `__declspec(deprecated)` since 13.10 (Visual Studio 2003)
- MSVC supports `__declspec(deprecated(message))` since 14.0 (Visual Studio 2005)

You can also use `[[gnu::deprecated]]` in recent versions of clang in C++11, based on `__has_cpp_attribute(gnu::deprecated)`.

I have some macros in [Hedley](https://github.com/nemequ/hedley) to handle all of this automatically which I keep up to date, but the current version (v2) looks like this:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && (__cplusplus >= 201402L)
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED(since) [[deprecated("Since " #since)]]
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED_FOR(since, replacement) [[deprecated("Since " #since "; use " #replacement)]]
#elif \
  HEDLEY_GCC_HAS_EXTENSION(attribute_deprecated_with_message,4,5,0) || \
  HEDLEY_INTEL_VERSION_CHECK(16,0,0) || \
  HEDLEY_ARM_VERSION_CHECK(5,6,0)
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED(since) __attribute__((__deprecated__("Since " #since)))
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED_FOR(since, replacement) __attribute__((__deprecated__("Since " #since "; use " #replacement)))
#elif \
  HEDLEY_GCC_HAS_ATTRIBUTE(deprcated,4,0,0) || \
  HEDLEY_ARM_VERSION_CHECK(4,1,0)
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED(since) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED_FOR(since, replacement) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
#elif HEDLEY_MSVC_VERSION_CHECK(14,0,0)
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED(since) __declspec(deprecated("Since " # since))
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED_FOR(since, replacement) __declspec(deprecated("Since " #since "; use " #replacement))
#elif HEDLEY_MSVC_VERSION_CHECK(13,10,0)
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED(since) _declspec(deprecated)
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED_FOR(since, replacement) __declspec(deprecated)
#else
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED(since)
#  define HEDLEY_DEPRECATED_FOR(since, replacement)
#endif
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out how to get rid of the `*_VERSION_CHECK` and `*_HAS_ATTRIBUTE` macros if you don't want to use Hedley (I wrote Hedley largely so I wouldn't have to think about that on a regular basis).

If you use GLib, you can use the [`G_DEPRECATED`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html#G-DEPRECATED:CAPS) and [`G_DEPRECATED_FOR`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html#G-GNUC-DEPRECATED-FOR:CAPS) macros. They're not as robust as the ones from Hedley, but if you already use GLib there is nothing to add.

Answer (score 4):

Dealing with portable projects it's almost inevitable that you at some point need a section of preprocessed alternatives for a range of platforms. #ifdef this #ifdef that and so on.

In such a section you could very well conditionally define a way to deprecate symbols. My preference is usually to define a "warning" macro since most toolchains support custom compiler warnings. Then you can go on with a specific warning macro for deprecation etc.
For the platforms supporting dedicated deprecation methods you can use that instead of warnings.

Answer (score 1):

For Intel Compiler v19.0, use this as `__INTEL_COMPILER` evaluates to `1900`:

```
#  if defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
#    define DEPRECATED [[deprecated]]
#  endif
```

Works for the following language levels:

- C++17 Support (/Qstd=c++17)
- C++14 Support (/Qstd=c++14)
- C++11 Support (/Qstd=c++11)
- C11 Support (/Qstd=c11)
- C99 Support (/Qstd=c99)

The Intel Compiler has what appears a bug in that it does not support the `[[deprecated]]` attribute on certain language elements that all other compilers do. For an example, compile v6.0.0 of the (remarkly superb) [{fmtlib/fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library on GitHub with Intel Compiler v19.0. It will break. Then see the [fix in the GitHub commit](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/commit/744302add085f30120c57f73cddbcb826cc92de9).

Comment: This is incorrect; C++ attributes do not work in C mode on ICC.  [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/JVJBwZ).  `__attribute__((deprecated))`, OTOH, works in C and C++ going back to at least ICC 13.0, probably much further (Intel tends not to document this type of stuff so I can't be sure).