# Marking library functions as deprecated/unusable without modifying their source code

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a large codebase that uses a number of unsafe functions, such as `gmtime` and `strtok`.  Rather than trying to search through the codebase and replace these wholesale, I would like to make the compiler emit a warning or error when it sees them (to highlight the problem to maintenance developers).  Is this possible with GCC?

I already know about `__attribute__((deprecated))`, but AFAIK I can't use it since I don't have control of the header files where these functions are declared.

Comment: If you could change the library source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295120/c-mark-as-deprecated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a custom header `deprecated.h`. In there, create your own wrapper functions, `deprecated_strtok()` etcetera that merely call `strtok`. Mark those with `__attribute__((deprecated))`. Below those definitions, `#define strtok deprecated_strtok`. Finally, use `-include deprecated.h`

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is that I have to repeat the entire function signature, and a transcription error (or slight change in interface between gcc/libc versions) can produce mysterious linkage errors.  However, using this strategy I can use both `__attribute__((deprecated))` for suggestions, and `#pragma GCC poison` for mandates.

Answer (score 7):

Try this in a source file, with a gcc enough recent it should avoid developers using these both functions.

```
#pragma GCC poison gmtime
#pragma GCC poison strtok
```

The downside of it is that it is only valid for one compilation unit. If you use precompiled headers (which you surely do if your project is big), you could put them there. At least this solution does not involve decorating function declarations in system headers and works at compile time.

Poison is maybe a bit hard as it produces errors and not warnings. Does anyone know how to weaken it? At least it is a nice way to enforce a DO NOT USE FUNCTION xxx policy.

Comment: I'm happy with an error.  I'll check this out.  Also, no, we do not use precompiled headers.  Linkage dominates our build-time already (and doesn't parallelize so nicely), so there's no benefit in optimizing the compilation side of it.

Comment: Do you have to make sure that you don't include any standard headers after using the poison pragma? Or does it only error for function calls and not declarations?

Comment: Poisoning reacts on both usage and declaration. That adds the constraint you mention. I am using it at the end of the precompiled header and did not really care about this before.