# Where can I find information on the C++ [[deprecated]] attribute

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I got sent a [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deprecated) describing a `[[deprecated]]` attribute in C++11. This sound pretty convenient, and I would like to have more information about it - which compilers support it, full documentation on it, etc.

I spent 20 minutes or so googling around, but *apart from the linked website*, I couldn't find infos on this *anywhere*. Partly, this was complicated by other uses of the word "deprecated" in connection with C++11, and search engines not recognizing `[[`. I didn't find this in draft standards linked to in various SO answers, either. I don't have access to the full, paid, standard.

**Does anybody have more information about this `[[deprecated]]` attribute?**

*P.S.: If you're curious, I'd use this as a better alternative to https://stackoverflow.com/a/295229/599884*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `[[deprecated]]` attribute has made its way into the draft of C++14 (see section 7.6.5 [dcl.attr.deprecated] of [the October 2013 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)).

> The *attribute-token* `deprecated` can be used to mark names and entities whose use is still allowed, but is discouraged for some reason.

For example, the following function `foo` is deprecated:

```
[[deprecated]]
void foo(int);
```

It is possible to provide a message that describes why the name or entity was deprecated:

```
[[deprecated("Replaced by bar, which has an improved interface")]]
void foo(int);
```

The message must be a string literal.

Comment: a link to the draft doc would be great :-) edit: thanks!

Comment: A nice reference about attributes (as well as many other C/C++ language and standard libraries features) is cppreference.com. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes for `[[deprecated]]`.

Answer (score 7):

First, things in `[[]]` are not keywords; they are attributes.

Second, there is no `[[deprecated]]` attribute defined by the C++11 standard. The link you're referring to is either in error or referring to a specific compiler (C++Builder, perhaps?) that implements this attribute.

Attributes are (usually) compiler specific. Like `#pragma`s, compilers are supposed to ignore any attribute they don't support.

Comment: thanks. keyword felt wrong somehow, but I wasn't sure, so I took the "Go Up to Keywords" link on that page to mean that it's a keyword. corrected. And thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Nicol: "compilers are supposed to ignore any attribute they don't support". That sounds logical, but where do I find that in the standard, please? I remember looking for it some time ago, in vain.

Comment: @Marc : §7/1: "*Except where otherwise specified, the meaning of an attribute-declaration is implementation-defined.*". §7.6.1/5: "*For an attribute-token not specified in this International Standard, the behavior is implementation-defined.*" Supposed to, not required to. :-]

Comment: I know this is just a "thank you" comment, but still, it is nice to read about this feature because it has been there for years in other modern languages like Java...