# How to deprecate function when return type changes c++

Tags: c++, api, deprecated

What strategies are there for deprecating functions when their return type needs to change? For example, I have:

```
BadObject foo(int); // Old function: BadObject is being removed. 
Object    foo(int); // New function.
```

`Object` and `BadObject` are very different internally, and swapping their return types will break code for current users of my library. I'm aiming to avoid that.

I can mark [`BadObject foo(int)` deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295120/c-mark-as-deprecated), and give users time to change affected code.
However, I [can't overload `foo` based on return-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type). `foo` is very well named, and it doesn't need to take extra parameters. How can I add the new function to my library whilst maintaining the old version, at least for a while?

What's the strategy to deprecate the old function without breaking too much dependant code, while providing users the time to migrate to the new version? Ideally I'd keep the current function name and parameter list, because it's named quite well now. It feels like this *should* be a reasonably common problem: what's a decent way to solve it?

Comment: Well, if users used auto everywhere, instead of manually typing the return type, everything would work automagically :).

Comment: This doesn't help you now, but C++11 inline namespaces are perfect for this. Declare `foo` in `inline namespace v0`, when a change is required declare `foo'` in `inline namespace v1` (and remove the `inline` from `v0`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the solution **will** force you to change your function names, but it'll be a compromise between your old users and your new ones.

So - rename the old `foo` into `deprecatedFoo` and your new `foo` into `foo2` (or anything you want). Then, in the header file you include with your library, you can simply:

```
#define deprecatedFoo foo
```

and inside the function itself do:

```
#warning ("This function is deprecated. Use 'foo2' or change the #define in LINE in file HEADER.")
```

Users of the old versions won't have to change their code, and will be issued a warning, and the new users will probably listen and change the `#define` in order to use the new `foo`.

In the next version you'll just delete the old `foo` and the `define`.

Comment: Did you mean that `#define` the other way?  As is, users of the new function will get the same number of warnings as users of the old function.

Comment: The users of the new version should get the warning, so they can (if they want) change. If you did the `#define` in an opposite way, the code wouldn't be compatible with the older versions. But I guess that's a choice that the OP will have to do, and we're not the ones to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a classic example is [Boost's Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/structure/include.html).

From their [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/faq.html#spirit.faq.i_m_very_confused_about_the_header_hell_in_my_boost_spirit_directory__what_s_all_this_about_):

> While introducing Spirit V2 we restructured the directory structure in
>   order to accommodate two versions at the same time. All of
>   Spirit.Classic now lives in the directory
>
> boost/spirit/home/classic
>
> where the directories above contain forwarding headers to the new
>   location allowing to maintain application compatibility. The
>   forwarding headers issue a warning (starting with Boost V1.38) telling
>   the user to change their include paths. Please expect the above
>   directories/forwarding headers to go away soon.
>
> This explains the need for the directory
>
> boost/spirit/include
>
> which contains forwarding headers as well. But this time the headers
>   won't go away. We encourage application writers to use only the
>   includes contained in this directory. This allows us to restructure
>   the directories underneath if needed without worrying application
>   compatibility. Please use those files in your application only. If it
>   turns out that some forwarding file is missing, please report this as
>   a bug.

You can ease migration by keeping the new and old versions in separate directories and using forwarding headers to maintain compatibility. Users will eventually be forced to use the new headers.

SDL 2.0 has a different approach. They don't provide a compatibility layer but instead a migration guide walking the users through the most dramatic changes. In this case, you can help users understand how they need to restructure their code.

Answer (score 0):

What if to make your `Object` class inherit from `BadObject` (which you'll keep temporarily)? Then the old user code won't know about that, so it won't break provided that your new "foo" function still returns your objects correctly.