# Compile-time detection of deprecated API calls?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, static-assert

Is there any new, cool feature in C++11 that allows us to detect **at compile time** whether an API now marked as deprecated is actually called by someone?

From what I've read about the new `static_assert` feature it doesn't seem flexible enough to be used in that kind of analysis.

But is there anything else we could use?

Optionally, is there anything in boost allowing that kind of compile-time checking?

Comment: marked as deprecated how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295120/c-mark-as-deprecated

Comment: The comment from @TheOne is a good solution.

Comment: @melak47 Sorry for being fuzzy - Well, let's say the decision has been made the API call is not to be used anymore whilst keeping binary compatibility. So some kind of compile-time notification mechanism I suppose is what we're looking for..

Answer (score 7):

With C++14 you will have that option :

```
#include <iostream>

void foo( int v ) { std::cout << v << " "; }

[[deprecated("foo with float is deprecated")]]
void foo( float v ) { std::cout << v << " "; }

[[deprecated("you should not use counter anymore")]]
int counter {};

int main() {
  foo( ++counter );
  foo( 3.14f );
}
```

Clang gives the compilation output ([here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3088b477dcbc8bdd)) :

```
main.cpp:12:10: warning: 'counter' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  foo( ++counter );
         ^
main.cpp:9:5: note: 'counter' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int counter {};
    ^
main.cpp:13:3: warning: 'foo' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  foo( 3.14f );
  ^
main.cpp:6:6: note: 'foo' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
void foo( float v ) { std::cout << v << " "; }
     ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: This warnings will cause the compilation to fail if you choose to treat the warnings as errors?

Answer (score 1):

Whether `static_assert` is too inflexible depends on requirements that you haven't specified, but if you want to *disallow* calls to deprecated APIs in *your* library, and those functions are templates, then it's perfect.

**More likely you wish to emit some sort of *mere warning* when such calls are made and, to my knowledge, there is no new C++11 feature to do that.**

Generally, C++ doesn't provide fine-grained control over specific compiler diagnostics/output, only "can compile" and "cannot compile" (though this is a gross over-simplification, the principle holds).

Instead, [you will need to rely on compiler-specific features such as `__declspec` and `__attribute__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295229/560648).

Comment: Hmm, so what about something that prevents compilation - but only, if the API method is actually called by somebody?

Comment: @cacau: Remove the function. (You're not really talking about deprecation any more.)

Comment: Luckily, we'll get `[[deprecated]]` in C++1y, [dcl.attr.deprecated]

Comment: @dyp: Indeed. Can't wait!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a language specific feature, it is rather compiler specific.

If an API call is marked as deprecated then your compiler should emit a warning notifying you about.