# Force compilation to fail if a struct member with a particular name exists

Tags: c++

Suppose `bad_name` is a restricted identifier for example that I do not want to be part of the struct. I am looking for a mechanism to force a compilation failure in that case.

example.h

```
struct example {
  int okay_name;
  int bad_name; 
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "example.h"

int main() {
  example ex;
  // cause compilation to fail here if bad_name is a member of ex

  return 0;
}
```

There are probably ways to cause a failure at runtime by simulating reflection, but is there a way to do this at compile time?

Comment: C++ have reflection?? so you want to make sure struct `example` don't have member called `bad_name`? maybe SFINAE with `static_assert` will work

Comment: You might add a `#define bad_name forbidden name` to `example.h`

Comment: What sort of "restricted identifier" did you have in mind?

Answer (score 4):

You can define `bad_name` to be something that would cause a compile time error. For example, nothing:

```
#define bad_name
```

gives on GCC

> error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
>
> int bad_name;

Answer (score 4):

You can simulate static assertions in C like this:

```
#define bad_name xxx; char static_assertion_bad_name_used[-1];

struct example {
  int okay_name;
  int bad_name;
};
```

which in GCC gives:

```
main.c:6: error: size of array ‘static_assertion_bad_name_used’ is negative
```

The advantage of this technique is that the error message gives you a reminder of what the problem is (even if slightly obscurely).

**Update** After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c) I found out that MS Visual Studio does not include the actual variable name in the error message if the array size is negative. Here is an alternative:

```
#define bad_name xxx; int static_assertion_bad_name_used : 0;
```

The error message in GCC is then:

```
main.c:5: error: zero width for bit-field ‘static_assertion_bad_name_used’
```

and apparently something similar in VS.

Also if using a more up to date compiler you can use [_Static_assert](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlc121.aix.doc/language_ref/sadecc1x.html), which would be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following:

```
#include <cstdint>

#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U>                                                   \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static std::uint8_t check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);           \
        template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);               \
    public:                                                                 \
        static                                                              \
        constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t); \
    }

DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_bad_name, T::bad_name, decltype(&T::bad_name));
```

Then check with a `static_assert` (need C++11):

```
static_assert(!has_bad_name<example>::value, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose bad_name is a restricted identifier for example that I do not
>   want to be part of the struct. I am looking for a mechanism to force a
>   compilation failure in that case.

This is not fully portable, but at least in VC++ and GCC you can mark the identifier as [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295120/c-mark-as-deprecated) and, if you want, elevate the warning it gives to an error.