# Prevent or generate warning for custom deprecations

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, c++11, cross-platform

I'm using C++11's `static_assert` to perform compile-time checks to prevent the use of insecure functions, and/or to provide feedback to the user when a new feature should be used and the relevant APIs are out of date (e.g. using `std::strftime`, `std::to_string`, etc.).

I want to force failure if any source code attempts to use outdated functions, but I need it to be totally cross-platform, and also bypass or workaround other 'helpers' such as Microsofts own deprecations.

I see I can use .sections when working with a gnu toolchain, which I can see the definition for in OpenBSD's cdefs.h (http://ninjalj.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/your-own-linker-warnings-using-gnu.html) but I have nothing equivalent for Visual Studio.

For example, I can use the following code without a problem to prevent `strcpy`/`strcat`:

```
#   define COMPILE_TIME_CHECK(expression, message)      static_assert(expression, message)
#   define GUARANTEE_FAILURE            (0 == 1)
#   define DISABLED_FUNCTIONS_MESSAGE_CSTRING   "strcpy, strcat must be replaced with strlcpy and strlcat, respectively"
#   define strcat       COMPILE_TIME_CHECK(GUARANTEE_FAILURE, DISABLED_FUNCTIONS_MESSAGE_CSTRING);
```

it may be unclean but works; but the trouble is when attempting to do the same with others that don't play as nicely, such as `ctime` and `localtime`:

```
_CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE(localtime_s) static __inline struct tm * __CRTDECL localtime(const time_t * _Time)

1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\time.inl(86): error C2059: syntax error : 'static_assert'
```

Is there a way I can block specific functions (warning or compile failure), while providing a message for what to use in their place, without conflict from gcc/visual studio in a suitable way? The CRT macros in visual studio do not prevent the above error with the aforementioned defines.

I'm not convinced something like `__declspec(deprecated) int strcpy(char*,char*);` (as noted here: [C++ mark as deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295120/c-mark-as-deprecated)) is going to always play ball, and is a lot more work & less descriptive than just setting a define for the function name.

Comment: Minimum Visual Studio 2012 and GCC 4.8 (pretty much from decent C++11 support)

Comment: VS2012 lacks decent C++11 support.  Consider 2013?

Comment: As you can see from the error, I'm already using 2013 - in any case it doesn't resolve the available choices I have.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Disable:warning {#warning Code}