# When using [[deprecated]] the warning is given 3 times

Tags: c++, c++14

I found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21192071/3098505) which describes the use of `[[deprecated]]` as  a `C++14` feature to instruct the compiler to warn about the use of deprecated functions.

I tried using this in a simple function within a project - the warning was issued 3 times. I initially thought this might be multiple template instantiations, so I tested a simple program.

```
[[deprecated]] void doNothing() {}

int main(){
    doNothing();
}
```

`g++ -std=c++14 deprecatedTest.cpp` outputs

```
deprecatedTest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
deprecatedTest.cpp:4:5: warning: 'void doNothing()' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     doNothing();
     ^
deprecatedTest.cpp:1:21: note: declared here
 [[deprecated]] void doNothing() {}
                     ^
deprecatedTest.cpp:4:5: warning: 'void doNothing()' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     doNothing();
     ^
deprecatedTest.cpp:1:21: note: declared here
 [[deprecated]] void doNothing() {}
                     ^
deprecatedTest.cpp:4:15: warning: 'void doNothing()' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     doNothing();
               ^
deprecatedTest.cpp:1:21: note: declared here
 [[deprecated]] void doNothing() {}
```

Is the warning supposed to be printed 3 times? (To get more attention?)

This seems a strange behaviour, but I can't imagine a simpler test.

Comment: Funnily, on g++ 4.9.2 it is printed twice. With clang it is only printed once.

Comment: Seems this is compiler specific (perhaps unsurprisingly?). A (rapidly) deleted answer also highlighted that `clang++` prints only once. I used `g++ v5.2.0` to get 3 outputs - interesting to learn that `v4.9.2` gives it twice. Hopefully there will be an answer explaining why, although I don't know that it will really help anyone (unless it also explains how to get it only once)

Comment: mingw 4.9.2 prints the message twice. Replace `doNothing()` with `auto f = doNothing; f();` and it will be printed only once :)

Comment: GCC trunk issues two warnings; one at the beginning and one at the end.

Comment: @T.C. For the code in the question, or for `auto f = doNothing; f();` ? Either way, good to know. *Edit* My gcc trunk finished compiling - it's twice for the question's code, once for the `auto f = ... ` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an obvious Quality of Implementation issue, and not likely to be intentional.

<strike>Just raise it on GCC Bugzilla if it's not already there.</strike>

[OP has raised this on Bugzilla, as suggested](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67960). ☺

Comment: Added a bug after a few comments indicating this was version dependent. There was already a presumably related/similar/same bug for the `attribute` syntax for deprecated

Comment: @chrisb2244: Ya wanna link us to it?