# Want Clang to ignore multiple directories when performing diagnostics

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy, catkin

I have the problem that clang not only checks my code but also 3rd party lib's and automatic generated code for the diagnostic flags which I provided. How can I tell not to do so?

I use `catkin-tools` and clang to build my c++ project where I use a config file for catkin  which provides the cmake args

```
cmake_args:
# Enable most warnings
- -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -isystem=/usr/include/eigen3/
```

Initially I wanted to add `-Wfloat-equal` as a diagnostic and the build should fail if it is found somewhere. But while building I found out that there are multiple paths which I need to exclude from the diagnostic check like

```
 /usr/include/eigen3
 /opt/ros/melodic
 ~/ws/src/devel/
```

I tried to add `/usr/include/eigen3/` as a system header path, but this did not work. So how do I exclude the listed directories ? For `clang-tidy` I used the `.clang-tidy` file where I specified the `header-filter` via a regex

```
 HeaderFilterRegex: '.*/ws/src/.*'
```

which works as intended. And for the regex I can also exclude the one sub folder in my `ws`. Unfortunately the `-Wfloat-equal` is only part of the [clang diagnostics](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wfloat-equal) but not of [clang-tidy diagnostics](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/list.html)

Comment: According to [How to suppress Clang warnings in third-party library header file in CMakeLists.txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707123/how-to-suppress-clang-warnings-in-third-party-library-header-file-in-cmakelists), `-isystem` is the way to do it.  You said you tried that but did not give details.  Could you show a minimal example that uses `-isystem` but Clang still reports warnings in that directory?

Comment: @ScottMcPeak I provided the `DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`of my build script and all the folders  which I want to "exclude" from the diagnostics in my post. I expect `isystem` to also go throug all subdirectories. E.g I dont want to see any diagnostics from eigen3 so I tried `-isystem=/usr/include/eigen3/` (with and without the last `/`) and `-isystem='eigen3` which both did not work, I still get diagnostics which complains for example about  `/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h` violating `-Wfloat-equal``. Maybe in the next days I can provide a minimal working exmaple to reproduce the error