# std::binomial_distribution<int64_t> << operator triggering warning C4244 for MSVC

Tags: c++

I am working on a codebase that is using `std::binomial_distribution<int64_t>`. When compiling with MSVC warning level 1, `/W1`, I get the following warning message.

```
warning c4244: 'argument': conversion from '_Ty' to 'long double', possible loss of data.
```

The code that triggers this looks something like this.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>

std::binomial_distribution<int64_t> distribution;

std::string saveState()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << distribution;
    return ss.str();
}
```

If I change the template parameter from `int64_t` to `int32_t`, the warning goes away.

I've read through the documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/binomial_distribution). The template parameter description states,

> IntType - The result type generated by the generator. The ffect is undefined if this is not one of short, int, long, **long long**, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or **unsigned long long**.

which implies that `int64_t` is a valid template parameter.

Any idea why I'm getting this warning and how I might go about fixing it?

Comment: `long double` in MSVC is a scam. [It's still 64 bits like a `double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/type-long-double?view=msvc-170), so its ability to hold a 64 bit integer without damaging it when stuffing it into the 52 bit mantissa cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Weird, the same result `std::binomial_distribution<> distribution(1LL);` does not throw the warning.

Comment: @273k the conversion happens when outputting to a stream

Comment: @user4581301 **it's not a scam**. The standard just requires the size of types like this: float <= double <= long double, char <= short <= int <= long <= long long. Lots of platforms that don't have hardware support for floating-point types longer than 64 bit have `long double` the same as `double`. GCC also allows you to choose between 64, 80 and 128-bit `long double`

Comment: @phuclv that sounds like the sort of spiel you get from someone who actually believes the moon landings were real. Next you'll be telling people the world's flat.

Comment: The warning comes from inside the standard library implementation. It isn't your fault and there isn't anything you can do about it. You are using the class correctly. The implementation shouldn't cause this warning.

Comment: @user17732522 that's what the standard says, have you even read it? Don't say stupid things if you're not a language lawyer. You talk like you're a flat earther. There are tons of compliant embedded systems' compilers where `long double` is 64-bit. Why on earth should it spend lots of code space for something like that

Comment: @phuclv I'll assume that you meant to tag the other anonymous user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user17732522 pointed out in his comment that the warning is coming from MSVCs install of the C++ standard library headers. The general guidance I've found online is that these kind of warnings are something that Microsoft needs to fix and not something my build process should report. Fortunately there are some compiler specific flags that ignore these types of warnings. The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707123/how-to-suppress-clang-warnings-in-third-party-library-header-file-in-cmakelists) cover the available options for different compilers. I've quoted the relevant parts below.

> gcc and probably also clang disable some warning for system include files. So if you specifies your headers directories with **-isystem** command line option in place of -I it should work.

> Here is the [MSVC blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/customized-warning-levels-and-code-analysis-for-external-headers/) where they talk about the new compiler functionality.
>
> > The “Ninja” and “NMake Makefiles” generators now use the MSVC “**-external:I**” flag for system includes. This became available as of VS 16.10 (toolchain version 14.29.30037).

> There is a way to suppress warnings from third party headers in a CMake way.
>
> ```
> target_include_directories(<target> [SYSTEM] [AFTER|BEFORE]
>    <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items1...]
>    [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items2...] ...])
> ```
>
> The **system keyword** is most likely what you want.

> For a while there was no solution for MSVC until recently in **CMake 3.22**, because the MSVC compiler finally added support for this.

**EDIT**

The above solution works for include paths explicitly added in CMakeLists.txt files, but does not work for default system include paths. To fix that, an additional compile option is needed as described in the [MSVC Compiler Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/external-external-headers-diagnostics?view=msvc-170).

```
add_compile_option(/external:W0)
```

Comment: `The general guidance I've found online is that these kind of warnings are something that Microsoft needs to fix` which guidance are you talking about? Are they people who work on the C++ standard or understand it? Those "guidance" are the thing that should be fixed. MSVC is just as C++ compliant as gcc or clang. You can still get the same issue on other compilers if you imply `long double` has more than 64 bits of precision

Comment: The warning is not generated by code I've written. It is generated by code written by Microsoft developers in their implementation of the standard library, so yes they should be fixed, but not by MSVC users.