# How to trigger a warning when a certain function is called (not compiled)?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, clang++

If we write:

```
void foo() {
#warning "Danger Will Robinson!"
}
```

we'll get a warning when *compiling* `foo()`. Now, What I want to do is for the compilation not to emit a warning, but for a warning to be emitted if `foo()` is *called*.

Is that possible, using g++ and/or clang++?

Note: This question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295120/c-mark-as-deprecated?noredirect=1&lq=1), about marking functions as "deprecated" (a-la C++14's `[[deprecated]]` attribute). However, it's a different semantic. I do not want people to get the notion that my function is deprecated, but rather get a custom warning.

Comment: I am afraid that's not possible the way. I'd rather go for a [`deprecated` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295120/c-mark-as-deprecated) in that case.

Comment: How could the compiler tell if a function is called or not? Consider `if (run_time_function() > 40173) foo();`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz should handle it the same way it handles the deprecated attribute.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It can tell when it encounters the call.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I think that would be an answer. "No" is a valid answer, no need to mark as a dupe. Plus, in my case, the semantic is not "deprecated"; but I'll clear that up.

Comment: @einpoklum You can write that as answe yourself. The duplicate already answered in a way that it's doing exactly what you asked for. The semantics can be changed in any way you want giving an additional message.

Comment: How is the behavior you ask for different from `[[nodiscard]]`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's not doing what I asked for, because it's saying that the function is deprecated, which is not the case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: There's no return value, for example. Other than that, yes, it's similar to `[[nodiscard]]` and `[[deprecated]]`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I could write that as an answer myself, had the question not been closed again...

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant `[[deprecated]]`.

Comment: @einpoklum could you add what kind of warning you want to add? It's a bit weird to get a warning when calling a non-deprecated function. Do you want it to warn about freeing the return value, or something like that?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Arbitrary warning. It could be: "Calling this function costs the company money1" It could be: "Calling this function may cause a nuclear explosion". It could be: "You are calling an untested function". etc.

Comment: @einpoklum hmm. Interesting. I am voting to reopen this question as it's absolutely not a duplicate.

Comment: @einpoklum How about something like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T4M354)? A bit hacky, but gets the job done

Comment: If GNU  is on the table, then there is `__attribute__ ((warning ("message")))` - Though I'm not sure it's exactly what you are after. Dead code elimination can  remove the warning should the call be on the eliminated branch.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica that's quite a bit more elegant than what I was proposing. The only problem being it doesn't work with clang.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: This is good enough, as I said I was willing to be compiler-specific. Is this avaialable in clang as well?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: clang-only, but does seem to be more robust than one might expect... Nice :-) Too bad the question is closed.

Comment: @einpoklum mine works with GCC too! https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1h7zsT (I still suggest you go with the other option)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Reopened. Would you like to make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4):

C++11 added `_Pragma`, which is like `#pragma` but macros can expand to it. So, you can make a macro, that expands to this warning and the function:

```
#include <cstdio>

void foo() {
  std::puts("foo is called!");
}

#define foo(...) _Pragma("message \"Danger Will Robinson!\"") \
  foo(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() { 
  foo(); 
}
```

The main issue with this approach is that it will not respect overloads and warn on any function with the name `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion from @StoryTeller in the comments, which works - partially - in GCC:

```
 __attribute__ ((warning ("Danger Will Robinson!"))) 
void foo() { }

int bar() {
    const int x = 123;
    foo();
    return x;
}
```

Why "partially"? As @StoryTeller says:

> Dead code elimination can remove the warning should the call be on the eliminated branch

Have look at [This GodBolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/58G3E8): When you enable optimizations so that the function is inlined - the warning attribute is ignored.